# PHP 5.3.5 Windows installer missing php_ldap.dll

Tags: windows, apache-2.2, php, ldap

I'm working with Windows Server 2008, Apache 2.2. I'm using php-5.3.5-Win32-VC6-x86.msi as the installer, using the threadsafe version. I've gone through the install process four or five times just to make sure that I'm not missing anything ridiculous, but I don't think I am.

The problem is that the php_ldap.dll extension simply doesn't seem to exist. It's not present in the installer interface (where the user is asked to choose which extensions to install), and it definitely doesn't appear in the ext/ directory after install.

I found a lot of mentions of this issue for 5.3.3, including links to download the extension individually. Those links no longer exist, of course, and besides: they were for 5.3.3. I'd really rather use an extension that belongs with PHP 5.3.5.

Anyone else encounter this problem? Any ideas as to what's going wrong? Anyone seen acknowledgement by the PHP folks that the file is indeed missing, and that it's an oversight?

It's quite a frustration because the server I'm building has no purpose if I don't have PHP LDAP support.

Cheers all, and thanks in advance for your assistance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This dll is located in this downloadable zip file: [php-5.3.5-Win32-VC6-x86.zip](http://windows.php.net/downloads/releases/php-5.3.5-Win32-VC6-x86.zip)

Does this help you?

Comment: Yes! Thank you very much. I thought I had checked that file already, but may have inadvertently been looking at the wrong zip. It's working now!

Comment: Link is dead.  Possible alternative: http://windows.php.net/downloads/releases/archives/php-5.3.5-nts-Win32-VC6-x86.zip

Answer (score 1):

The above link (php-5.3.5-Win32-VC6-x86.zip) is dead. Can not find the 5.3.5 zip for vc6. Thus i got `"PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: ldap: Unable to initialize module"`.

Edit: Finally, I used the php_ldap.dll contained in [5.3.4](http://windows.php.net/downloads/releases/archives/php-5.3.4-Win32-VC6-x86.zip)
and seems to work for now.

php: php-5.3.5-Win32-VC6-x86.msi
apache: httpd-2.2.17-win32-x86-no_ssl.msi
windows: win 7 (64 bit)